# Selenium - I can't click button in dialog "Before you continue" in google

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome

I have a problem , click button in dialog forms in google.
This is my code :

```
@BeforeEach
public void startDriver() throws InterruptedException {
    // Start Chrome browser
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\gecko\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl");
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Test strony google")
public void testGoogle() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Rozpoczecie testu strony google");
    ModelStatistic modelStatistic = new ModelStatistic();
    System.out.println(modelStatistic.getTimestamp());
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    WebElement agree = driver.findElement(By.id("introAgreeButton"));
    agree.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='q']"));
    name.sendKeys("Kamil Surma");
}
```

Selenium Cant's see Webelement agree.

I agree

Comment: Hi, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Which is `Before you continue` button on Google Home Page?

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#introAgreeButton"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)

Comment: Before you continue is a name of dialog form when I write https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl  it show , but I want to click button "I Agree" WebElement agree = driver.findElement(By.id("introAgreeButton"));

Answer (score 1):

Add this:
`driver.switchTo().frame(0);`

before that:
`WebElement agree = driver.findElement(By.id("introAgreeButton"));`

The button is in iframe and driver can't find it.

Comment: Here is the code for Python in case someone needs it: 
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
print("begone foul demon of google terms")

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this:
`driver.wait(until.ableToSwitchToFrame(0));`
instead
`Thread.sleep(4000);driver.switchTo().frame(0);`

It will switch automatically

Comment: Thank you  very much , bug is resolved.         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver , 5000);
        wait.until(driver -> driver.switchTo().frame(0));
        WebElement agree = driver.findElement(By.id("introAgreeButton"));
        agree.click();

Answer (score 0):

This code might help.
locate the consent form agree button.

```
WebElement consent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"L2AGLb\"]/div"));
consent.click();
```