# selenium - issue with policy/cookies

Tags: python, selenium

**issue**: i cannot click 'zgadzam sie'. **error occurs** "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']"}"

**question**: how can i handle it?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjI5j.png)
[english image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qEEk.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']").click()
driver.quit()

time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sleeping after you are attempting to click the button.  You are also quitting the driver before sleeping which is another problem.

Consider using the [WebDriverWait().until()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) function to ensure that the element is loaded instead of relying on some arbitrary amount of time:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']"))
)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']").click()
```

---

The reason why you are getting this error is because the [element is nested in an `<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747406/selenium-i-cant-click-button-in-dialog-before-you-continue-in-google).  This can be resolved by waiting for the iframe to appear, then waiting for the button to be loaded, then finally clicking the button:

```
# Wait for the iFrame to be available to switch to it
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(0)
)

# Wait for the button to be available within that iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']"))
)

# Finally click the button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']").click()
```

Comment: still error occurs:

 File "c:\Users\dawid\Desktop\test12.py", line 12, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='RveJvd snByac' and text()='Zgadzam się']"))
  File "C:\Users\dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: You either you need to increase the timeout duration (so increase wait until time) or the element XPATH is not correct.  If you can confirm that the element appears within 10 seconds, then it is likely the latter.

Comment: i did it^, i increase timeout duration and i try different locators to use but still i got the same error

Comment: Can you update your post with the full stack trace of the error and the other selectors you attempted to use.

Comment: Also, I can't check myself rn (not on computer) but it is possible that element class names are being generated with random names to prevent people from scraping.  Meaning they will change every time you load the page.  If so, then your current XPATH selector will never work and you will need to create one that doesn't rely on the class name.  Simply removing "@class='...'" from the selector may work if this is the case and there is no other place in the web page where the text "'Zgadzam się'" appears.

Comment: still the same :/. I change it to "//*[text()='Zgadzam się']" but still does not work. if you open incognito window and put in browser "www.google.com" you will get the "policy" window - and if you or anybody can try to check and handle the error I would apreciate!

Comment: @Dawid_N I don't get a policy window in incognito mode

Comment: about first case that there can be generated random names to prevent people from scraping its not possible for this example. I refresh plenty times and the DOM looks the same

Comment: @Dawid_N what does the popup say in English?

Comment: I just edit main post and i add the same image in english, please check up

Comment: maybe there is possible to use selenium via normal mode (not incognito)?

Comment: @Dawid_N very strange issue.  i see some people complaining about the popup here on the google forums recently [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/66791382?hl=en).  It is unfortunate that I cannot test this myself because I have never seen this popup before...  It is possible that the popup is nested inside of a `<iframe>` which would explain why Selenium cannot find the element.

Comment: @Dawid_N updated my answer.  Like [this post states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747406/selenium-i-cant-click-button-in-dialog-before-you-continue-in-google), its because its in a different iframe, so selenium cant scrape it.  If this resolves your answer, I would appreciate it if you could please click the green checkmark to mark your post as resolved.

Comment: @Dawid_N no problem dude!  Glad to hear that worked.  Please mark this as the answer so your post appears as resolved :).

Comment: i guess i do not have 250 rep. points yet its why I cannot close the topic

Comment: @Dawid_N you don't need to close it (that is something different). there should be a green checkmark you can click to the left of each answer which will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full xpath. You can find it by using an xpath tool usually downloaded as a browser extension.