# Selenium Java - unnable to click on Google Search

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I saw a lot of threads with this issue but none is working for me as I tried almost all possible methods and still get error "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted"

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Driver//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("568567546754");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@role='search']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]//center/input[1]")).click();
    
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("3462355452354");
    //Parent-child relationship xpath - Define xpath for parent
    //body/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]
    
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]"));
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']/center/input[1]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]")).click();;
    //Thread.sleep(2000);
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='introAgreeButton']/span/span")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google Search")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys();

    //driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
    //driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: where are you getting the error? Usually this means there is an overlay, or other element, covering the element you want to click. Have you identified this yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747406/selenium-i-cant-click-button-in-dialog-before-you-continue-in-google SOLUTION!

Comment: Yes I managed to solve it as per the above link. It seems I had to switch to the frame in order to agree and then to click on the google's search button.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it will work. As Enter will do the same thing as clicking on the Search button.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("568567546754" + Keys.ENTER);
```

Here I'm not using the xpath for search text field as I've found name attribute.
You can send the search text and Enter in one shot.

Comment: can also work without using "+"





driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("568567546754", Keys.ENTER);

Answer (score 1):

You can use Action class here.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys("568567546754");
Robot ab = new Robot();
ab.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this reduced Xpath : //input[@name='q'] or `driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("568567546754");`

or you can try this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("\$x("//input[@name='q']")[0].value="Car"\");
```

check out this code snippet

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class SearchAction{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
      // identify element
      WebElement p=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      //enter text with sendKeys() then apply submit()
      p.sendKeys("Selenium Java");
      // Explicit wait condition for search results
      WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
      w.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul")));
      p.submit();
      driver.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul,I have tried all possible methods (I guess)  but does not work. Thanks!