# python selenium Unable to locate element for Google map term and service

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the search for the short google link via this code:

```
link = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sport+La+Pava/@41.273359299999996,2.0005245,14z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sSport+La+Pava!3m4!1s0x12a49d5b3d4b1753:0xeb7e41655fa9ec91!8m2!3d41.273359299999996!4d2.0005245'
from selenium import webdriver
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(3)
button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton")
button1.click()
new_https = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/jsl/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/input').value_of_css_property()
```

print(new_https)

the link is a google map link.
The error happen at button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton"). The button I am trying to get through here is basically the term and condition. I have to accept it. but everytime I receive the error NoSuchElementException

I have tried different method: using Xpath, full Xpath, css, nothing work.
I use the same code for website like amazon.com all work fine there, so it is not about the location of my webdriver or anything like that. it seems quite Google term and condition specific

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747406/selenium-i-cant-click-button-in-dialog-before-you-continue-in-google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick pointed out, this question has been answered (code was in javascript) Here is the code in Python for thoe who need it:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0) 
driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
```